# How to edit New Menu in command bar in SharePoint site home page and add a new link in the menu and hide existing item

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-online-powershell

I have a requirement to edit the New Menu of command bar in the home page of a SharePoint team site and add new link in the menu and hide the "Document Library" option. Please suggest any ideas[image: New Menu] to achieve this functionality.